# Question about proof for $f\in C^1\Rightarrow f$ is local Lipschitz continuous

Tags: calculus

I have found the following proof in this very forum:

> If $f:\Omega\to{\mathbb R}^m$ is continuously differentiable on the open set $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}^d$, then for each point $p\in\Omega$ there is a convex neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that all partial derivatives $f_{i.k}:={\partial f_i\over \partial x_k}$ are bounded by some constant $M>0$ in $U$. Using Schwarz' inequality one then easily proves that
>   $$\|df(x)\|\ \leq\sqrt{dm}\>M=:L$$
>   for all $x\in U$. Now let $a$, $b$ be two arbitrary points in $U$ and consider the auxiliary function
>   $$\phi(t):=f\bigl(a+t(b-a)\bigr)\qquad(0\leq t\leq1)$$
>   which computes the values of $f$ along the segment connecting $a$ and $b$.
>   By means of the chain rule we obtain
>   $$f(b)-f(a)=\phi(1)-\phi(0)=\int_0^1\phi'(t)\>dt=\int_0^1df\bigl(a+t(b-a)\bigr).(b-a)\>dt\ .$$
>   Since all points $a+t(b-a)$ lie in $U$ one has
>   $$\bigl|df\bigl(a+t(b-a)\bigr).(b-a)\bigr|\leq L\>|b-a|\qquad(0\leq t\leq1)\>;$$ therefore we get
>   $$|f(b)-f(a)|\leq L\>|b-a|\ .$$
>   This proves that $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous in $U$ with Lipschitz constant $L$.

I was wondering what exactly the $d$ in the first and fourth indented line is referencing.
Is this an operator or does it refer to the $d$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$? What does it express in combination with the $f(x)$ or $m$ respectively?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It is just notation for the derivative. $df(x) = \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$.

Comment: The proof quoted above was [given by Christian Blatter](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/73426/79365). (It's a good practice to identify the source of quoted material more precisely than just saying it's from elsewhere on Math.SE).