# Continously differentiable funcion is locally lipschitz

Tags: analysis

As proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73368/a-continuously-differentiable-map-is-locally-lipschitz) for example, a continuously differentiable function is locally lipschitz.

But does the converse hold? Is there a function (maybe even on $\mathbb R$) that is locally lipschitz but not continuously differentiable?

I thought of $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R, x\mapsto |x|$ which satisfies the lipschitz condition for $L=2$ (even globally) but it is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: so, what is the question? Your counter-example is correct.

Comment: Then my question is answered. Thanks!